# What are the best practices to use named queries in Entity classes?

Tags: hibernate

I am using named queries in my Hibernate Entity classes with annotations.
What are the best practices I should follow if multiple queries per entity class?

```
Note: We have ruled the idea of putting queries in any property file or hbm.xml file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = User.byUsername, query = "select u from User u where u.username = :username"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.follows, query = "select u from Follow as f inner join f.following as u where f.user = :user")})
public final class User extends Base implements UserDetails {

   static public final String byUsername = "User.byUsername";
   static public final String follows = "User.follows";
...
}
```

You can then reference `User.byUsername` etc everywhere else, so only one string reference. And you get all the predicto intellitext goodness. Like below :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.getNamedQuery(User.follows);
```

Comment: IN my case UI is passing query names but it is a useful tip. Thanks